# Python Tools for Visual Studio erroneous autocomplete only for OpenCV library

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012, ptvs

Im using PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio). In my project, I use an external library, OpenCV, (referenced locally, not using pip/easy_install). Autocomplete/intellisense on this library only always displays nonsense characters (e.g. "Àt4èÚ" or "ÇEüÿÿÿÿè").

Everything else is fine, I can run my code and I can autocomplete other libraries/functions. What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using PTVS 2.0 beta, and are hitting [this bug](http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/731) (note the last comment to it). The problem is basically that Intellisense for interpreter-wide libraries is driven by a database, and the utility that is used to build that database has a bug in 2.0 beta that prevents it from working correctly with binary Python modules (.pyd).

The bug has been fixed, and if you [download and build](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Build%20Instructions%20for%20PTVS) the most recent source code for PTVS from CodePlex, you will get the fix. It will, of course, be included in the next release. Using the stable version (PTVS 1.5) will also deal with this issue, though, of course, you will not get all the new features in 2.0.